# How to make a character move around on a screen using Scheme?

Tags: vector, scheme, implementation

In a screen that is divided into rows and columns using a vector of vector implementation, how do I make a character move around on keyboard input? 
I already have the following to make create the coordinates for the character:

```
(define direction 'up)
(define (next-pos x y)
    (cond ((eq? 'up direction)
           (cons x (- y element-height)))
          ((eq? 'down direction)
           (cons x (+ y element-height)))
          ((eq? 'left direction)
           (cons (- x element-width) y))
          ((eq? 'right direction)
           (cons (+ x element-width) y))))
```

Comment: It seems unclear what you asking exactly. Are you asking about how to get the keyboard input? Are you asking how to draw the character on the screen? Is this a graphical game, or text-based, Rogue-like game? If so, are you asking about how to "draw" chars in a terminal? Are you asking how to store the coordinate data of the character Right now the question is too broad and/or ambiguous to be answered. Please clarify so your question can be answered. Also, please include which implementation of Scheme you are using since that could heavily influence the answer on this.

Comment: Both home and the arrows are characters you can write to a terminal so you have the power to move up to the top left and rewrite the the screen or only the parts that has changed using arrows. I've done that since the 80s and the standard [hasn't changed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) and it has nothing to do with the choice of programming language.

Comment: @Sylwester I see. I was thinking of whether bindings to [curses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_(programming_library)) would be available or if some other terminal manipulation library would be used (for example, the [charterm](https://docs.racket-lang.org/charterm/index.html) package for Racket). Given your point, I see now I was making the situation overly complex.

Comment: @eestrada Different Scheme implementations can have different support for libraries such as ncurses, but they would not be portable. You would get locked in on the implementation you use and cannot run your software on other implementations in the future. eg  do it in racket and you cannot run it in chicken. SRFIs are semiportable where it can be done in Scheme, but if it needs new primitives you are locked in on the subset of implementations that support that SRFI.